# External USB disk drive cannot be remounted in Windows XP

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sleep

I have Maxtor Basics Desktop 1TB external USB drive connected to Windows XP. The dirve's firmware puts it to sleep after 10-20 min of inactivity and then the drive cannot be mounted unless I reset it via power connector.
While in sleep mode I can see the device in the Device Manager under both Disk drives and USB sections.
Is there a way to get the drive out of sleep mode without hard reset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Windows XP USB Guide](http://www.usbman.com/WinME%20USB%20Guide.htm) :

> **USB Device Stops Working or Won't Resume**
>
> - WinXP by Default turns off USB Root    Hubs to Conserve Power causing some
>     devices not to resume correctly after 
>     Windows resumes from sleep,
>     hibernation or computer inactivity
> - In the Device Manager -> Universal Serial Bus Controllers -> USB Root Hub
>     -> Power Management, Uncheck the box per the illustration below.  Uncheck
>     all boxes on all root hubs.

**EDIT**

From this thread :
[Sleep (aka Power management) problem with external USB (Maxtor Basics)harddisk](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/forums/storage/sleep-aka-power-management-problem-external-usb-maxtor-basics-harddisk-216376.html)

> I downloaded from Seagate the [Maxtor OneTouch Lite](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=ot4-downloads&vgnextoid=0ed72c9e46914110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD) software (and inside
>   is a program named "Maxtor Manager"),
>   which was NOT recommended for my
>   Maxtor Basics Desktop drive. If
>   installed, I can select my external
>   drive and I can set the sleep
>   intervall. That solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks but I already unchecked this.